How to add data labels to a choropleth map in Python?
I'm trying to teach myself how to make map-based data visualizations in Python using my current country of residence, Ireland, and a very basic data point, population density. I'm happy with what I've produced so far (see below), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to add labels to each of the counties - either the county names as found in my ENG_NAME_V column or the data themselves as found in my density column. My code so far is also below.
I've looked through several threads on this, and I think using fig.add_scattergeo would be the best solution here (as discussed here and here), but my code just keeps spitting out AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_scattergeo' whenever I try that.
I'd be grateful for any pointers or suggestions - I'm quite new to this particular area of Python so your I appreciate your patience as  I figure this out.
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get data

county_pop = pd.read_csv('my_desktop_path\\geoplotting\\ireland_population.csv')
county_pop

#process data

shapefile_path = 'my_desktop_path\\ireland_shapefiles\\Counties_-_National_Statutory_Boundaries_-_Ungeneralised_-_2024\\Counties_-_National_Statutory_Boundaries_-_Ungeneralised_-_2024.shp'
counties = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
counties

county_pop = county_pop.rename(columns={'county': 'ENG_NAME_V'})
county_pop['density'] = county_pop['population']/county_pop['area']
county_pop

gdf = counties.merge(county_pop,on='ENG_NAME_V')
gdf

#plot data

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
gdf.plot(ax=ax, column='density', cmap='RdYlGn_r', legend=True)

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_title('Population Density of Irish Counties (2019)', size = 18)

plt.show()



You don't have a plotly's choroplet here! You're making a plot from  GeoPandas that provides a high-level interface to matplotlib.. Check-out the duplicate to see how to label each county/polygon ;).
